# Animating ng-move in AngularJS ngRepeat is animating the wrong items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I'm a little flummoxed when it comes to animating ng-move in an ng-repeat. If I move an array item from 3 to 7 for instance, items 4-7 get shifted up and they animate. However the actual item I moved from 3 and placed in position 7, does not. Here's a plunkr demonstrating my issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4yRkLWbsU57YxrYOrWUQ?p=preview

Moving item 7 to 3, however, works as I expect, animating the single moved item, and not the items that have been pushed down.

This is not very useful for showing a user what moved.  How should someone properly animate an ng-move?

Comment: Chris, any progress on this?

Comment: Nope, sorry.  I ended up finding this issue on github but I never got a satisfactory course of action.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5160

Comment: upvote for using the (highly under-rated) term "flummoxed"

Answer (score 1):

@tasseKat has an excellent answer, which explains the behavior you observed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27616435/1652643

However, his solution is not as simple as you would wish... but so far I haven't found anything better.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
arrayVar.splice(to, 0, arrayVar.splice(from, 1));
```

To remove and return an element at the index `i` of array `arr`, use `arr.splice(i, 1)`,

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  Unfortunately, that appeared to work because it triggered ng-enter and ng-leave.  I updated the plunkr to show the animations differently.

Comment: @Chris I didn't get it. I think my fix still works. You don't need `[0]`

Comment: By returning array.splice(i, 1), you are returning an array, not the element.  This triggers the ng-leave/ng-enter, not the ng-move transitions in AngularJS. The plunkr is just the simplest case I could do to illustrate that ng-move (which is actually triggered during a sort in my real code) is not animating the actual moving item.  I updated the plunkr to show leave/enter/move as red/green/blue.  It's the blue animations that are my problem.  I'm sorry for the confusion.